# Replacing elements in a nested list, BUT leaving some input unchanged

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I have a nested list (ie., one list containing lists) and I want to replace *parts* of the nested lists.

```
list = {
  {"a", "b", "Take whatever is in here"}
}
```

I want to have the following result

```
{
  {"c", "d", "Take whatever is in here"}
}
```

My approach was using Replace[] and a placeholder.
However, how do I get the content of the placeholder?

```
{{"a", "b", _} -> {"c", "d", **???**}}
```

Comment: Try  `list /. {"a", "b", x_} :> {"c", "d", x}`  .  Note the use of `:>` instead of `->` .

Comment: Top! You can just copy it as answer :)

Comment: @LouisB could you copy it as answer, so I can accept your solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I thought this was straightforward to find in the docs, but, apparently, this is an edge-case.

Assuming we know only, as the OP put it, the "placeholder" `_`, the documentation provides the following suggestive example:

> ```
> In[1]:= f[x_] := (x + 1)^2
> In[2]:= {f[1], f[a + b c]}
> Out[2]= {4, (1 + a + b c)^2}
> ```

which might give a hint about the `x_` construct.

It's very helpful to search for, e.g., "named patterns" in the documentation. Check [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NamingPiecesOfPatterns.html) as a starting point, but do read through the many other linked pages as well. Patterns are probably the most important and fundamental part of *Mathematica* and are one of the first things to learn.

I'll leave it to @LouisB to post the actual answer from the comments if he so wishes.

Answer (score 1):

The way we get the contents of the placeholder is to give the blank pattern a name.  Then we refer to the name, as follows

```
Clear[x]
list = {{"a", "b", "Take whatever is in here"}};
list /. {"a", "b", x_} -> {"c", "d", x}  (* do not use this *)

(*  {{"c", "d", "Take whatever is in here"}}  *)
```

The code above produces the right answer, this time, but it is not recommended.  We notice that Mathematica uses different color coding for the `x_` on the left and `x` on the right.  Why aren't they the same?

What would happen if we forgot to `Clear[x]` and `x` already had a value?

```
x = "bug";
list /. {"a", "b", x_} -> {"c", "d", x}  (* do not use this *)

(*  {{"c", "d", "bug"}}  *)
```

In the above, if we `Clear[x]` we would lose its value.  We could use a different name, like `y`, but the real solution is to use RuleDelayed (:>) instead of Rule (->), as

```
x = "bug";
list /. {"a", "b", x_} :> {"c", "d", x} 

(*   {{"c", "d", "Take whatever is in here"}}   *)
```

Now we notice the color coding for `x_` and `x` is the same (in Mathematica).  They are both local variables, instead of one local and one global.